# How do I take an array indicating the indicies of another array and store those values in yet another array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6 in Jupyter Notebooks.

So, I have an array that indicates the indices of another array, for  example,

```
[10, 123, 320, 800]
```

would correspond to entry 10, entry 123, and so on. These are the indices of value of interest in another array, around 700 entries long. I need to take these indicated entries and store them in a separate array.  I also need to keep all the entries in the same chronological order they were in before I started. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of indices is stored as variable `i` and your main list as variable `l`, you can use the following list comprehension to construct a list with values that correspond to the values of `l` as indicated by indices in `i`:

```
[l[n] for n in i]
```

Comment: Ah i see. i should have mentioned I am using a set() function and it appears to not support this. My code looks like i = set(list1) & set(list2) and n  is a long array containing the entries. using your code, I get the error 'set object is not subscript-able'. Even storing the output of the set array in another array and then using your code return this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sets do not keep orders and are not indexable, so if you want to be able to "keep all the entries in the same chronological order they were in before", then you should use lists instead.

Comment: Ok I see. Mt only issue is I don't know of a way to find the differences between the two lists I know of is with using the set function. Using lists, I am unable to use & because it is not supported and all the other examples I can find use the set function to find the common elements between two lists.

Comment: You can always convert a list to a set on the fly using the `set()` constructor when set operations are needed.